# How to install pecl_http on PHP 5.5.31 on MAC OS X el capitan?

Tags: php, http, pecl

I am trying to install pecl_http extension. I installed pear, pecl, autoconf & then I tried to install the pecl_http( as 2.5.5 version of pecl_http is compatible with PHP 5.5.31 ) by following command.

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http-2.5.5
```

But I found few errors as below:

```
configure: error: Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/pecl_http/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn-dir=/usr' failed
```

so I run following ( as 1.1.2 version of raphf is compatible with PHP 5.5.31 )

```
sudo pecl install raphf-1.1.2
```

But its showing error as follows:

```
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/raphf/php_raphf.h'
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/raphf
```

Has anyone had a similar experience? Please suggest the steps I need to follow to install pecl_http on MAC OS X el capitan with PHP 5.5.31.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't just write things to `/usr`; you should be able to specify a prefix of `/usr/local` to pecl, and even then you may need to use `sudo`. Really what you should be doing is using a package system like MacPorts or Homebrew.

Comment: I have installed pear, pecl inside /usr/local/bin/, but how to install raphf to this location. Whether I need to go to that folder inside and after that I will run 
sudo pecl install raphf-1.1.2
Please suggest.